# Creating a sparse file in Java on NTFS

Tags: java, windows, nio

This command should create a sparse file:

```
channel = Files.newByteChannel(path, EnumSet.of(CREATE,WRITE,SPARSE));
```

However, it just creates a regular (non-sparse) file. I can manually turn it into a sparse file using `fsutil` on the command line, but how can I get the Java Runtime to do this?

I am using Java 11 on Windows 10 (NTFS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, creating a sparse file only works with `OpenOption` **`CREATE_NEW`** (which replaces any existing file), but not with `CREATE` (which only creates the file if it doesn't exist).

```
channel = Files.newByteChannel(path, EnumSet.of(CREATE_NEW,WRITE,SPARSE));
```